# Is there a URL that gets you to a random Stack Exchange network site?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

Sometimes I feel like I want to use some sort of URL which redirects to a random site on the Stack Exchange network for the purpose of discovering new, interesting and useful Stack Exchange network sites.

[image: random.stackexchange.com does not exist]

Comment: It should be easy enough to create that... alternatively, just pick something from the Hot Network Questions.

Comment: Code highlight on Meta is pretty minor, no need to edit just to add it. Thanks for the efforts though!

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry I just love when everything works 100% correctly. though I will learn my lesson now, thank you for your effort too, sheriff -)

Comment: Actually I approved your latest edit, [two others deemed it too minor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26385).

Comment: @ShadowWizard ye, I've already read the history of that edit. -)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking [Sklivvz's advice](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/228057/152859) I built a jsfiddle that will redirect you automagically to a random site.

Since the API call is "heavy" and limited, please don't run the below code too many times.

Let's cut to the slack!

The Random Stack Exchange™ Site Jumper Turbo is here:

```js
var jumperDiv = $('#Jumper');
jumperDiv.html('Loading, please wait...');
$.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?page=1&pagesize=999&?jsonp=wrapperFunc", function(data) {
    $('#RemainingQuota').html('Quota remaining: ' + data.quota_remaining + '<hr />');
    var allSites = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        //don't take meta sites
        if (data.items[i]["site_state"] != "linked_meta")
            allSites.push(data.items[i]["site_url"]);
      }
    Jump(allSites);
});
    
function Jump(allSites) {
    var randSiteUrl = allSites[parseInt(Math.random() * allSites.length)];
    jumperDiv.html('<a href="' + randSiteUrl + '">Jump to</a> ' + randSiteUrl + '!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="RemainingQuota"></div>
<div id="Jumper"></div>
```

Comment: wow! :)

how to read the code of this jsfiddle? It auto-runs every time I click the link

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd see my edit. :)

Comment: JSFiddle broken here. Luckily there is still the code.

Comment: @Pat yeah, weird. Maybe like imgur, they remove inactive fiddles. Using stack snippet instead now.

Comment: @TheBitByte good point, done. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It jumps sometimes to meta sites.

Comment: @TheBitByte yeah, I don't filter the list... but I should. Thanks!

Comment: What about grabbing all the sitenames until the quota is finished, filtering meta sites out, and having a "random site" button that grabs sites from that internal list and displays them?

Comment: Or, a crazier solution, manually grab the names from the HTML of stackexchange.com/sites. Not sure how reliable that solution would be if the page changes or new sites are added to it, though.

Comment: @TheBitByte can't do those, it's client side and can't read remote pages, only the API which provides JSONP.

Comment: @TheBitByte that's what I was referring to, can't read the HTML of stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: You mean stack snippets can't access remote pages? I guess maybe they're sandboxed or something.

Comment: @TheBitByte any client side JavaScript code is restricted to read contents only of the same domain as the server where it sits, yes. Stack Snippets, jsfiddle, all of them. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of sites here as JSON:

http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true

(call without help page: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites)

From that, it should be a Javascript one liner...

```
$.get("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=1000", function(data) {
  console.log(data.items[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.items.length)]["site_url"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no such URL as of now, but the closest you can get to it is the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) url. You can randomly select a StackExchange site.

<sup>* To make it really very random, you can click on a random space in that page by closing your eyes ;)</sup>

Comment: perhaps I will write some js code for getting random url from this page. Thx!

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd - Well yeah, that could work too :)

Comment: btw sir what's that letters in your nickname? Auto completion (after at sign) doesn’t seems to work on you, weird o_0

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd - Since this is my post, you need not refer me using the `@` symbol. SE has handled that. And regarding the special characters, well those are some unicode characters I picked up from the internet and on any other post which is not mine, but I've commented, you can very well use the `@` symbol to address me. It works :)

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd now you can use `@`, when you will press it the weird name will auto appear as its first character is special.